# New to Android Dev - Problem installing SECOND App/APK

Tags: android, sdk

I am writing some test Android apps using Eclipse.  I created my 1st project, a simple hello app, built the apk (app1.apk), and was able to install and run that on an Android tablet.

I then created a new project in eclipse, for a 2nd app.  I exported the apk (app2.apk).  But, when I try to install this 2nd apk (app2.apk) on the tablet, it warns me that it wants to REPLACE the 1st app.

When I built the apks, I used a different key for app1 vs. app2, and the project and class names are different, so what is it that the Android installer is using that makes it think that both apks are the same app?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the same package name in both apps.

Comment: Yup. You can use the same signing key, the same Java package names, the same sharedUserId, the same application name (and so on, and so on), but the package name in the manifest must be different for each app.

Comment: Christopher (and mbaird),  You're correct that the packagename in the Java code was the same in both apps.  But can you clarify what you said about the package name in the manifest being different?  Doesn't the package name in the manifest have to match the package statement in the Java code?  Jim

Comment: Yes it has to match the package in the Java code.  Thus you have to use a different package name for each app (in the code and the manifest)